# How to properly display JSON object with same name

Tags: javascript, html, json

I am trying to display a JSON object using Javascript and it all works fine but it won't print the second author in the var vb6book, I'm sure that I'm just writing it out wrong but I don't understand how to fix it... I need to print both authors in that object to the page for an assignment that I'm doing... please help! thanks!

Here is the JS code:

```
  var javabook = {
  "book": {
    "isbn" : "0-596-00016-2",
    "title"  : "Java and XML",
    "price"       : "39.95",
    "publisher"  : "O'Reilly &amp; Associates",
    "copyright": "2000",
      "authors": {
        "author": {
          "fname": "Brett",
          "lname": "McLaughlin",
          "price": "22.00"
        }
      }
    }
};

var vb6book = {
  "book": {
    "isbn" : "1-861003-32-3",
    "title"  : "Professional Visual Basic 6 XML",
    "price"       : "49.99",
    "publisher"  : "Wrox Press",
    "copyright": "2000",
      "authors": {
        "author": {
          "fname": "James",
          "lname": "Britt",
          "price": ""
        }
        "author": {
          "fname": "Tuen",
          "lname": "Duynstee",
          "price": ""
        }
      }
    }
};

var myJSON = JSON.stringify(javabook);
var myJSON2 = JSON.stringify(vb6book);

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myJSON;
document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = myJSON2;
```

And here is the HTML:

```
<p id="demo"></p>

<br>
<br>
<br>

<p id="demo2"></p>
```

Comment: You can't have object with 2 same property keys.
So you can not have 2 `author` keys for `authors` object.

Comment: You should use an array.

Comment: Oh gotcha! I'm new to JSON so I'm kind of struggling haha, I appreciate the help guys. It works great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have redundantly-named property keys.  I'd recommend using an array; something like this:

```
"authors": [{
          "fname": "James",
          "lname": "Britt",
          "price": ""
        }, {
          "fname": "Tuen",
          "lname": "Duynstee",
          "price": ""
        }]
```

Answer (score 0):

First JSON just have one author and that's why it doesn't have an error, the second one have error because and array of author should be write like this. `"Author": [
        { "name":"author0", "otherArrayIntoThis":[ "subArrayAuthor0", "subArrayAuthor1", "subArrayAuthor2" ] },
        { "name":"author1", "otherArrayIntoThis":[ "subArrayAuthor0", "subArrayAuthor1", "subArrayAuthor2"] },
        { "name":"author2", "otherArrayIntoThis":[ "subArrayAuthor0", "subArrayAuthor1", "subArrayAuthor2"] }
    ]`

Also you could use the same notation to do not have 2 JSON and just have one variable where storage whole books and access to info by dot notation like this in pure JSON format.

```
 `"books": [{
"isbn" : "0-596-00016-2",
"title"  : "Java and XML",
"price"       : "39.95",
"publisher"  : "O'Reilly &amp; Associates",
"copyright": "2000",
  "authors": {
    "author": {
      "fname": "Brett",
      "lname": "McLaughlin",
      "price": "22.00"
    }
  }
},{
"isbn" : "1-861003-32-3",
"title"  : "Professional Visual Basic 6 XML",
"price"       : "49.99",
"publisher"  : "Wrox Press",
"copyright": "2000",
  "authors": {
    "author": {
      "fname": "James",
      "lname": "Britt",
      "price": ""
    },
    "author": {
      "fname": "Tuen",
      "lname": "Duynstee",
      "price": ""
    }
  }
}]`
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried running your code.

There is a comma missing after the "authors" in `vb6book`:

```
var vb6book = {
  "book": {
    "isbn" : "1-861003-32-3",
    "title"  : "Professional Visual Basic 6 XML",
    "price"       : "49.99",
    "publisher"  : "Wrox Press",
    "copyright": "2000",
      "authors": {
        "author": {
          "fname": "James",
          "lname": "Britt",
          "price": ""
        }, // <--- I added a comma here
        "author": { // <--- This author key is a duplicate.
          "fname": "Tuen",
          "lname": "Duynstee",
          "price": ""
        }
      }
    }
};
```

If you try this code:

```
console.log(vb6book['book']['authors'])
```

The output is:

```
{"author":{"fname":"Tuen","lname":"Duynstee","price":""}}
```

You have a duplicate `"author"` key.